# EMACS: Warning (initialization): Setting HOME to C:\ by default is deprecated

Tags: emacs

So I just pasted my .emacs file from my macbook to my windows pc, and everytime I open emacs I get this warning:

```
Warning (initialization): Setting HOME to C:\ by default is deprecated
```

I've tried to google, but I'm not really sure what I can do to fix this. Anyone got an idea? Right now my .emacs file is in C:. What I would like the most is having emacs look in my D: drive, and of course not display this message each time I start.

Any idea how I can remove this message at startup?

Comment: What in your `.emacs` file relates to setting the HOME directory?  This is clearly not the default behavior.  Or, did you perhaps alter a Windows system setting to move your HOME directory?

Comment: After taking a quick glance, I can't say I see anything that relates to ~ or home inside the file. I could link to it, but last time I did, a mod came and said to not use external links. And I'm afraid the file is a little bit too large to share here. I haven't altered any Windows system settings, as far as I know.

Comment: If you start Emacs with zero customization, does the error message go away?  We call this **Emacs -Q** -- i.e., an empty/blank or nonexistent `.emacs` file.  This test will narrow down the problem to a system-wide setting or your `.emacs` file.

Comment: if I move the .emacs from root C: to the desktop (where it can't find it), I am greeted with the default starter setup for Emacs, instead of my custom settings. If I move the .emacs back, it goes back to my problem.

Comment: What do you get when you open a Windows command prompt and type `echo %USERPROFILE%`  This should be your HOME directory.

Comment: It echoed back as: "C:\Users\Username>". I tried putting the .emacs in there, but when I launched Emacs, it didn't have any customization.

Comment: Maybe it's a permissions issue with the home folder, or the folder where you installed Emacs?  The manual says the fall-back if it cannot access the home directory is to try the root  of the hard-drive to locate the `.emacs` file, which will generate the error message you received.  Here is the link to the manual:  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Windows-HOME.html

Comment: Emacs is installed under D:\. I fail to see how, but maybe that's the problem? I don't think it's a problem with permission, but can't say for sure.

Comment: I believe the solution is to put your `.emacs` in the `%appdata%` folder: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/efaq-w32.html#Location-of-init-file

Comment: That's a bad warning message, IMO. You did not "*set HOME*" at all. And Emacs should not care at all whether you set HOME or what you set it to. What it does care about is where to find your init file. The warning should be worded in terms of the location of your init file; nothing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Way back around the Emacs 21 days, Emacs used to default to C:\ as the HOME directory, as it was guaranteed to exist for everyone. This was fine when most users were on Windows 95/98/ME with no security, or on Windows NT/2000 with lax permissions (which at the time were pretty much required, since so many apps expected to be able to write to C:\, C:\Program Files and other dangerous locations).  But increasingly, corporate admins were preventing ordinary users from being able to write files in C:\, and these days it is the standard configuration for Windows (with the additional feature since Windows 7 that the application is tricked into thinking it has written the file, but actually it has gone somewhere else, and other applications cannot see it unless they look in the real location).

For backwards compatibility, Emacs still looks in C:\ to see if your .emacs is there when deciding where the default HOME should be, so if you are still relying on the ancient default behaviour, your configuration will not break.  But in the latest version, there is this warning, because with the security in modern versions of Windows, it just leads to confusion when you update your C:.emacs using a different editor, and Emacs does not see the changes.

The warning can be eliminated in two ways:

1. Explicitly set HOME in your environment, so that Emacs does not need to choose a default.  If you do this, HOME can be anywhere, "C:\", "D:\home" or wherever you want.
2. Move your .emacs file to the modern default HOME location, which you can find by moving your .emacs out of C:\ temporarily, starting emacs and `C-x d` `~/`.